NetworkManager bond0 permanent activating
I've upgraded a Centos7 server (physical server) to Rocky8 a few weeks ago.
It has network with two interfaces in a bond with VLANs.
But now I've seen in journalctl that NetworkManager is permanently activating the bond.
Connection was not so bad as it seems in the logs, but after I deleted the bond and configured it again, it was really unstable.
Connection for 30 seconds, than disconnected, after a while connecting, disconnecting...
It is only a active-backup bond, because LACP never worked on this server.
Now I've just configured the physical interfaces in the different networks and configured the access ports on the switch into the different VLANs.
This is stable now.
Any suggestions why bond is not working? I've a second server where bond is working, but this was setup as Rocky8 from beginning, not upgraded.
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8137] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8529] device (bond0.19): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8536] policy: auto-activating connection 'bond0' (37a4c8dc-559b-4461-b5b7-2a762e8b363c)
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8538] device (enp175s0f1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'dependency-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8544] device (enp134s0f1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'dependency-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8563] device (bond0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8573] device (bond0.19): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8584] device (bond0.1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8590] device (bond0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'user-requested', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8593] device (bond0): Activation: starting connection 'bond0' (37a4c8dc-559b-4461-b5b7-2a762e8b363c)
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8593] policy: auto-activating connection 'bond-slave-enp175s0f1' (b5172329-05d2-4292-9edf-bcea4e2760ad)
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8596] device (bond0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8597] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8603] device (bond0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8606] device (enp175s0f1): Activation: starting connection 'bond-slave-enp175s0f1' (b5172329-05d2-4292-9edf-bcea4e2760ad)
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8608] device (bond0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8609] device (enp175s0f1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8611] device (enp175s0f1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8613] policy: auto-activating connection 'bond-slave-enp134s0f1' (8b0d2952-47e1-45ae-a083-6dba91627682)
Nov 29 17:56:01 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899361.8617] device (enp175s0f1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.0272] device (bond0): attached bond port enp175s0f1
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.0272] device (enp175s0f1): Activation: connection 'bond-slave-enp175s0f1' enslaved, continuing activation
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.0279] device (enp134s0f1): Activation: starting connection 'bond-slave-enp134s0f1' (8b0d2952-47e1-45ae-a083-6dba91627682)
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.0280] device (bond0): carrier: link connected
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.0283] device (enp175s0f1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.0286] device (enp134s0f1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.0288] device (enp134s0f1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.0292] device (enp134s0f1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1874] device (bond0): attached bond port enp134s0f1
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1874] device (enp134s0f1): Activation: connection 'bond-slave-enp134s0f1' enslaved, continuing activation
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1880] device (bond0.19): carrier: link connected
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1881] device (bond0.1): carrier: link connected
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1883] device (enp134s0f1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1885] device (enp175s0f1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1888] device (bond0.19): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1891] device (bond0.1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1893] device (enp175s0f1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1895] device (enp175s0f1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1898] policy: auto-activating connection 'bond0.19' (9cfcc862-4b2f-4806-93d6-9b3d42401e08)
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1900] policy: auto-activating connection 'bond0.1' (e520ccd2-a2f4-404a-9ea4-8af0d311fd36)
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1901] device (enp134s0f1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1903] device (bond0.19): Activation: starting connection 'bond0.19' (9cfcc862-4b2f-4806-93d6-9b3d42401e08)
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1904] device (bond0.1): Activation: starting connection 'bond0.1' (e520ccd2-a2f4-404a-9ea4-8af0d311fd36)
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1904] device (enp134s0f1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1907] device (enp134s0f1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1909] device (bond0.19): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1911] device (bond0.19): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1913] device (bond0.1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1915] device (bond0.1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1917] device (bond0.19): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.1920] device (bond0.1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.2116] device (bond0.19): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.2121] policy: set 'bond0.1' (bond0.1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.2339] device (bond0.1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.2348] device (bond0.19): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.2351] device (bond0.19): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.2354] device (bond0.19): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.2358] device (bond0.1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.2359] device (bond0.1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.2361] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.2362] device (bond0.1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 29 17:56:02 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899362.2365] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899394.1476] device (bond0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <warn>  [1732899394.1479] device (bond0): Activation: failed for connection 'bond0'
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899394.2578] device (bond0): detached bond port enp175s0f1
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899394.4291] device (bond0): detached bond port enp134s0f1
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899394.4966] device (bond0.19): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to B6:27:AC:1D:03:38 (vlan-parent)
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899394.4967] device (bond0.1): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to B6:27:AC:1D:03:38 (vlan-parent)
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899394.5114] device (enp175s0f1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'dependency-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899394.5118] device (enp134s0f1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'dependency-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899394.5124] device (bond0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899394.5299] device (bond0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'user-requested', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899394.6341] device (bond0.1): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Nov 29 17:56:34 srv01.mydom.local NetworkManager[44717]: <info>  [1732899394.6347] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL


Well, it seems there was some confusion in the ifcfg-files under /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts.
Usually the name and device in e.g. ifcfg-enp134s0f1 is the same like in the file-name, but in this file there was device eno2.
So I cleaned up this files under /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts, reconfigured the bond and now it is stable.
Even with LACP it works now.
